# How to check the number of Microsoft Teams free remaining tenants

Tags: microsoft-teams

As a Microsoft Teams free tenants ,I know i have 300 maximum users. But Who can tell me how to check the number of Microsoft Teams  free remaining tenants

Comment: You mean free remaining users in a tenant? Tenants are GUIDs do there are a lot of those left. 

Answer (score 1):

Log in to https://ms.portal.azure.com/ and click on Azure Active Directory to view the license